# How to save the edited .nrrd files in python?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, save-image

So I am unable to save the resized nrrd file here

```
!pip install pynrrd
import numpy as np
import nrrd
import cv2
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

readdata,header = nrrd.read("/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/Image/imagingVolume .nrrd")
print('readdata: ', readdata.shape) #(256,256,30)

readdata = cv2.resize(readdata,(192,256))
readdata = np.transpose(readdata, (2,0,1))
print(readdata.shape) #(30,256,192)
cv2.imwrite("/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/","reshaped.nrrd")
```

> Overload resolution failed:
>
> - img is not a numpy array, neither a scalar
> - Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'img'

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: the `cv2.imwrite()` call is wrong. it takes a numpy array for the data, not another file path.